# Difference between a destructor in Python vs C++

Tags: python, c++, destructor

How do the contracts of a C++ destructor and a Python destructor differ, especially relating to object lifecycle and when resources are reclaimed? I haven't found a comprehensive side-by-side comparison.

What I think a C++ destructor does is that it entirely frees the memory held by the object. And Python deregisters the object but it still remains in the cache memory (calling it garbage collection), and then frees the memory entirely after the program is complete.

Comment: Can you show an example of a Python destructor, please?

Comment: A C++ destructor does what you define it to do.

Comment: @timgeb https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destructors-in-python/

Comment: @Julien I am not talking about adding custom functionalities to a destructor. I am talking about their technical nature in a vanilla form.

Comment: @SPSharan In both C++ and Python if you don't define a destructor than there is no "vanilla form". In C++ the destructor defaults to just a trivially empty function. Member objects are destroyed separately from the destructor and the memory for the object is release in a different step. In Python, if you don't provide a destructor then the object just doesn't have a destructor.

Comment: C++ destructors generally free any resources associated with the instance, since C++ doesn't have automatic garbage collection, file closure, etc.

Comment: Python destructors are generally only needed if the class has references to external resouces (e.g. files, network connections), because garbage collection takes care of references to other Python objects.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks for your answer. It clears up my understanding now.

Comment: @Barmar as well

Comment: @timgeb No. I was talking about what it does from a memory standpoint with respect to the objects it has created. Please check the updated question :) I hope its better now.

Comment: @SPSharan -- That site you linked to is notorious for bad code as well as bad (or wrong) explanation of basic things.  C++ has something called "deterministic destruction", which does not exist in Python.  An object goes out of scope in C++, it's destructor is invoked right then and there.  There is no "wait for the garbage collector to see the invalid object" thing going on in C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can my question be reopened and the comment posted as an answer?

Comment: C++ destructors aren't responsible for freeing the memory of an instance, that happens automatically when the variable goes out of scope (for local instances) or you use `delete` (for dynamic instances). It's needed for freeing other dynamic objects referenced by the instance.

Comment: C++ destructors are called at the moment the object goes out of scope. Python destructors, like Java finalizers, may not be; they wait till the object has been garbage collected. To get the same effect in Python, use context objects and the `with` clause, or `try...finally`.

Comment: Sone interesting reading on the subject: [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203)

Comment: @SPSharan `__del__` is not a destructor, and GeeksForGeeks not an authoritative source on the Python language, and indeed, is frequently just bad and wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liftime of a C++ object begins with its construction, and ends with its destruction. C++ assumes a system with limited amount of resources; Resource Aquisition Is Initialization. That just means every aquired resource is bound to an object and must be freed before the objects lifetime ends: the destructor is supposed to pay the debt of constructor. Otherwise a resource leak happens. Thus C++ defines 4 storage classes:

1. External objects trancende others they are created at beginning of the program(before main) and destroyed upon exit.
2. Static objects are much like external objects, but they can be a bit lazyier in construction and generally get destryed prior to external objects(things are more complicated)

**Do not  ever forget forget the initialization order *fiasco*.**

3. Automatic objects( function local objects or none static class data members) die when they go out of scope. Scope for function local variables is the closing curly brace **}** corresponding the nearest opening  curly brace **{** that embrace the object. None-static data members are killed by their parents. General rule for distructoin is that since new-commers build upon pioneers' work, each object may rely on the existance and validity of objects previously constructed: so automatic objects are destructed in the reverse order of construction(declaration).
4. Dynamic objects are the most dangerous ones. Compiler does not automatically put a bound on their lifetime; but the progrmmer must do. General rule is to delete every instance created by new. But that is easier said than done. So good practice is to avoid using naked new/delete pair and stick to smart pointer and generic container libraries that cautiously take care of the tricky parts.

But that is not all. In order to correctly implement RAII per class, one must be familiar with famous idioms. C++ Programmer must be able to utilize the **rule of 0/3/5** and he must be familiar with **copy/swap idiom** for not so time-critcal cases. Nothing is a must, but those 2 idioms can be good start points for general cases; specific cases need specific treatment (eg. Copy/swap does not do good with vector).